# Use array to store jQuery Selectors

Tags: jquery, arrays, css-selectors

I'd like to be able to have an array full of jQuery selectors as such (an array of class names). This is what I'm doing at the moment though it's not functioning:

```
var array = [$('.one'),$('.two')];
array[0].find('.box-text').attr('src',"myImage.png");
```

What's wrong?

Comment: That should work as long as the elements exist

Comment: _an array of class names_, actually that's an array of jQuery objects and it works http://jsfiddle.net/nWwtN/

Comment: Wow. Stupid mistake on my end. .box-text needed to be box-image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is it ok for you to do something like

```
var array = ['.one','.two'];
$(array[0]).hide()
```

Comment: And for those that would want to perform an action on all of those selectors, here is a sample:

`$(array.join()).show();`